# Maven/Sonar: Enforce usage of slf4j over different logging frameworks

Tags: java, maven, logging, sonarqube

we have a project with a lot of dependencies. Many of them also bring various kinds of logging frameworks with them.
This leads to confusion when writing new classes, because IDE auto complete suggests like 10 different imports for the class Logger or LoggerFactory.

To minimize confusion and to consolidate the project structure I'd like to only allow the usage of slf4j Loggers and break the build if a developer uses e.g. a log4j Logger.

Question: Is there a maven plugin that allows to specify forbidden classes and that breaks the build when usage of such classes is detected?
If not, is there a SonarQube rule that at least allows to report an issue in such situations?

Comment: Stackoverflow  is definetly not the place to ask for feature (your question is not a question)  : please reach out sonarqube mailing list : sonarqube@googlegroups.com as stated : http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/

Comment: FYI: I implemented a simple enforcer plugin rule to accomplish this: https://github.com/skuzzle/restrict-imports-enforcer-rule

Answer (score 3):

The [Architectural constraints should be followed](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AArchitecturalConstraint) rule template is probably what you want. It allows you to forbid access to certain packages (e.g. **.slf4j*.**).

In terms of breaking the build, that's not available from SonarQube in the current version of the server (5.2), but is there in 5.1 and should [return soon](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-123). So let's say you're on a version of the server that supports breaking the build. What you could do is create a rule from the Architectural Constraint template and give it Blocker severity in your profile. Then set a quality gate that fails on new Blockers and you're done.